# Tcp Variants Comparison in NS3

Tags: tcp, ns-3, congestion-control

I've started to work on NS3 to compare different TCP congestion Control Mechanisms.
I'm using an available TCP example named tcp-variants-comparison. It's using available method in NS3 like Reno, NewReno, etc.
The example producing 4 different outputs. Is there any one knew what exactly this 4 pcap files contains?
I have opened them using WireShark tool, but I can not figure out the meaning of information I have in every file.

Regards,

Comment: The PCAP files contain packet capture on each of the 4 net devices. The information should be self-explanatory in wireshark. They are either Tx or Rx packets, their type, their content (headers etc) and timings of each event. The scenario produces other outputs for analysis such as tracing of congestion window, rtt, rto and slow start threshold.

Comment: Thanks @Konstantinos, I don't need to go through the details which provided in PCAP files. I need to compare the performance of the mechanisms in total. Do you have any idea how I can use detailed data to calculate a throughput in total?

Comment: In order to compare two mechanisms, you need to identify some metrics for the comparison. For example you could use the congestion window and how it changes over time. For throughput comparison you could use FlowMonitor statistics. The usage is explained in documentation.

Comment: @Konstantinos I finally started to use FlowMonitor file. I changed Bandwidth and run the tcp-variants-comparison. Now I want to compare the throughput for, for example Reno while changing BW. But honestly I don't know how to calculate throughput using having a lot of information in Flow Monitor file. I searched and no success. Do you have any idea how I can do it?

Comment: This presentation for FlowMonitor explains how to calculate several metrics with the probes FlowMonitor provides http://telecom.inesctec.pt/~gjc/flowmon-presentation.pdf There is also a python script in /src/flowmonitor/examples/flowmon-parse-results.py to automatically parse the XML file.